# Images are not showing on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, parse-platform

So my image is downloading on the iphone 5s but they aren't showing up in the iPhone 6 in the cell. I'm using parse.com but this isn't a parse issue I think. Also, on the iPhone 5s when the image does load in the cell it causes slow scrolling and the images do not load until you pass them. I know that it's because I'm reusing the cell and it has to load, but is there a way to load the image quicker so it shows before you scroll to it in the cell? Any advice would be great. Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{

NSString *cellIdentifier = @"activityT";

ActTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *name = [[[object objectForKey:@"fromUser"] objectForKey:@"username"]copy];
NSString *place = [[[object objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"placename"]copy];
NSString *city = [[[object objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"city"]copy];
NSString *state = [[[object objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"state"]copy];

cell.context.text = [object objectForKey:@"recommendationText"];

[[cell name]setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[cell placeButton]setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@,%@)",place,city,state] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

cell.time.text = [formatter stringForTimeIntervalFromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:[object createdAt]];


cell.myImage.image = nil;
cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myImage.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

cell.myImage.file = [[object objectForKey:@"fromUser" ]objectForKey:@"profileImage"];
[cell.myImage loadInBackground];

cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;



cell.placeImage.image = nil;
cell.placeImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

if ([object objectForKey:@"postImage"]) {

    cell.placeImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"postImage"];

    if ([cell.placeImage.file isDataAvailable]) {

[cell.placeImage loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cell.placeImage.frame.size.width, 200);
    cell.eventImage.image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:size];


    }

}];
    }

}


return cell;
```

}

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
```

{

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.height), NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

Comment: Is it "placeImage" that's not showing up?

Comment: Yes.The other one is showing up but that's because it's a fixed thumbnail size. I'm scaling down the place image size to get the best quality. I can get.

Comment: Do you know what's going on Lyndsey?

Comment: Oh... I must've had a theory a few days ago when you posted this to know that you meant "placeImage"... I'll have to look it over again... (You need to tag a user in order for them to be notified when you reply to a comment underneath your own question.) But for one though, you should definitely *not* be scaling the image dynamically like that. Drawing in a context takes too much time and memory to do it quickly like that while scrolling.

Comment: Why do you have both "eventImage" and "placeImage" when they contain the same image? And which one isn't showing up? Or are both not showing up?

Comment: @LyndseyScott that's an error when copying it over on my part. It should be placeimage and not event image...I'm noticing that it's pretty expensive to dynamically scale the image like that. Would it just be easier to just create 2 different cells...1 with that image and 1 without?